# EMU8086 Assembly: Output generates the total number of bits instead of The number of 0s in the output

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

The task is to get a user input in decimal, produce the binary of it in 16 bits, then finding out the number of 0s in the binary output.
The first part of finding out the binary seems to work fine, but what did I do wrong in the second part? it's showing the total number of bits instead of the 0s.

Example: input: 3
Output: 0000000000000011
Number of 0s: 14

```
include "emu8086.inc"
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
zeroes dw ?
.code
    ;First part, user input in decimal then generating the output in Binary, 16 bits. --Works FINE

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    call scan_num
    printn
    
    print "The binary is: "
    
    mov bx, 16
    
    _loop:
    shl cx, 1
    jc bin_1
    
    putc '0'
    
    dec bx
    jnz _loop
    jmp exit
    
    bin_1:
    putc '1'
    
    dec bx
    jnz _loop
    
    
    ;Second part, finding out the number of 0 bits in the binary output
    mov cx, 16
    
    up:
    rol ax, 01h
    
    inc bx
    
    jmp next
    next:
    loop up
    mov zeroes, bx
    
    mov ax, bx 
    printn
    print "The number of 0s: "
    call print_num
     
    
exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
    
;define
define_print_num
define_print_num_uns
define_scan_num
```

Comment: `jmp next` to `next:` is a no-op; execution would fall through to the next instruction anyway. And you don't have any conditional branches in your second part, or anything that branchlessly reads CF as set by `rol` to do a conditional increment that way (e.g. `adc bx, 0`).  If you single-step your code in the debugger, it should be pretty straightforward to see that it just counts BX up to 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Think about this

If ever your input is an even number (0, 2, 4, ...), then your loop that displays the binary representation of the number will exit the program even before trying the second part! The `jmp exit` instruction should read something like `jmp SecondPart`.

On top of what Peter Cordes wrote in a comment, I would like to add that if *scan_num* gave you the number in the `CX` register and you stripped it clear in the first loop, there's nothing more to process in the second loop. Moreover in the second loop you expect the number to be in `AX`; does *scan_num* deliver its result in 2 registers at once???

### Now for the solution

Why even write a second loop if the first loop can additionally do the work of counting zeroes?
You don't need a *zeroes* (memory based) variable when you can use an available general purpose register.

```
        ...
        call  scan_num
        printn
        print "The binary is: "
        XOR   BP, BP     ; Clear counter
        mov   bx, 16
    _loop:
        shl   cx, 1
        jc    bin_1
    bin_0:
        INC   BP         ; Found an extra zero
        putc  '0'
        dec   bx
        jnz   _loop
        JMP   DONE
    bin_1:
        putc  '1'
        dec   bx
        jnz   _loop
    DONE:
        MOV   AX, BP
        printn
        print "The number of 0s: "
        call  print_num
    exit:
        ...
```

I have capitalized the changes so you can easily see the differences.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just extract the top bit (or bottom after rotate) to conditionally increment, and to putc with a register instead of constant after you `add al, '0'`.  But yeah, if you're going to keep the branching on every bit, that's sensible.